# C++11/Qt Memory leak despite moving

Tags: c++, qt

I want to generate a `QJsonDocument` using a language similar to XPath. For example give this set of parameters:

```
"#/node1/node2/val"
"hello"
```

Should yield:

```
{
   "node1":{
       "node2":{
           "val": "hello"
       } 
   }
}
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
QJsonDocument doc;

const auto ascending_construct = [&](const QString& json_pointer, QJsonValue val){
    auto components = json_pointer.split("/");
    //TODO: sanity check components
    auto inner = new QJsonObject {{components[components.size()-1], val}};
    auto current = inner;
    for(int i = components.size() - 2; i >= 1; i--){
        auto parent = new QJsonObject{{components[i], std::move(*current)}};
        current = parent;
    }
    return current;
};
QJsonObject root(std::move(*ascending_construct(json_pointer, value)));
```

But valgrind tells me that there is a memory leak. I know that I am constructing the `QJsonObject` on the heap, but I thought that dereferencing them and then moving them would "transfer ownership" to the `parent` and when the upper most parent is destroyed, it should propagate the destruction downwards.

How can this memory leak be fixed?

Comment: you need to `delete` what you `new`ed. Why do you use `new` when anyhow you immediately dereference the pointer and move from it?

Comment: `QJsonObject` has no `QObject` as a base class, so QT ownership rules don't apply here [qt ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html), and you have to use `delete` explicitly.

Comment: Dereferencing doesn't do anything to ownership. Here you are probably creating a copy when you do `std::move(*current)`.

Comment: QJsonObjects are [implicitly shared](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), there is no need for pointers in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::move` "hollows out" the referenced object but does not automatically `delete` it, so you are indeed leaking memory.
Luckily, this is not needed as QJsonObjects are implicitly shared. So:

```
const auto ascending_construct = [&](const QString& json_pointer, QJsonValue val){
    auto components = json_pointer.split("/");
    //TODO: sanity check components
    auto current = val;
    while (!components.isEmpty()) {
        current = QJsonObject{{components.takeLast(), current}};
    }
    return current;
};
QJsonObject root = ascending_construct(json_pointer, value);
```

Comment: ah this works because the QJsonObject within the loop creates a copy of the `current`. Very nice. Thanks!